# How can I create a user story without a sprint in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

I am using the Agile template in DevOps. I am currently collecting user stories from the business team. As I am capturing them, I don't know which sprint they will be in or if they will be kept in scope at all. However, DevOps forces you to select a sprint when you create the stories. So my question is this: Is it possible to create a User Story without associating it to a sprint? If not, what are the best practices for adding requirements and user stories to a backlog to be pulled into specific sprints later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your question about having new stories assigned to the backlog instead of a sprint at creation time...

Go to the Team Configuration page where you select iterations for the team. There is a Default Iteration field that is often set to  the current iteration. Change this to the level you regard as the backlog, then your new stories will be created on the backlog instead of a sprint.

Comment: I'm guessing I just missed this before, but I didn't see that I could select the "base" iteration (or "Project" as Daniel mentions in the other answer). Setting this as the default was just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sprints are just a hierarchy of nodes, which can optionally have dates assigned to them. With that in mind...

You define one as a team's backlog iteration, which is where all work not assigned to a sprint goes. This is, by default, the root iteration.

- Project (root iteration, by default your backlog iteration)

  - Sprint 1
  - Sprint 2
  - Sprint 3

You can create more complex hierarchies if you're managing multiple teams with different iteration schedules:

- Project

  - Team A (team A's backlog iteration)

    - Sprint 1
    - Sprint 2
  - Team B (team B's backlog iteration)

    - Sprint 1
    - Sprint 2

or even

- Project (Team A and B's backlog iteration; they both pull from the same backlog)

  - Team A (no longer has any specific meaning, just a node in the hierarchy)

    - Sprint 1
    - Sprint 2
  - Team B

    - Sprint 1
    - Sprint 2